# C# hack: assignment to "this"

Tags: c#, class, struct, this

All C# beginners know that `class` is a reference type and `struct` is a value one.
Structures are recommended for using as simple storage.
They also can implement interfaces, but cannot derive from classes and cannot play a role of base classes because of rather "value" nature.

Assume we shed some light on main differences, but there is one haunting me. Have a look at the following code:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public void AssignThis(SampleClass data)
    {
        this = data; //Will not work as "this" is read-only
    }
}
```

That is clear as hell - of course we aren't permitted to change **object's own pointer**, despite of doing it in C++ is a simple practice. But:

```
public struct SampleStruct
{
    public void AssignThis(SampleStruct data)
    {
        this = data; //Works fine
    }
}
```

Why does it work? It does look like `struct` **`this`** is not a pointer. If it is true, how does the assignment above work? Is there a mechanism of automatic cloning? What happens if there are `class` inside a struct?

What are the main differences of `class` and `struct` **this** and why it behaves in such way?

Comment: "It does look like struct this is not a pointer." Bingo. Structs are value types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: agreed.  structs "MOSTLY" live on the stack

Comment: @TMcKeown, no, they don't. Not always, anyway.

Comment: @AntP Thanks, it is fair, but let's imagine: value type object assigns itself to other. In which way?

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk I'm not sure what you mean by that. But I have a feeling that the answer is "by value."

Comment: @TMcKeown Value types live where they've been defined, reference types always live on the heap.

Comment: @AntP I mean that behavior of `struct` `this` looks some confusing

Comment: @lightbricko Thanks, now we know struct's this assignment clones even read-only fields. But why is it happening?

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk it's a "feature", really :-)

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk It works that way, because it was specified to work that way. It’s all in the answer for the linked question.

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk I'm not arguing that it's not confusing (in this context), which is why it's probably not a very good idea to use it.

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk simply because it is the way it is supposed to work. You can read section 7.6.7 in the C# 5.0 language specification: http://www.ecosia.org/url?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdlx%2Fthankyou.aspx%3Fid%3D7029&v=2&i=0&q=%227.6.7%22%20%22c%23%20language%22&p=0&tr=508&at=0&ar=0&ab=0&mr=0&ir=0&kgr=0&nr=0&iar=0&sr=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This section of the C# specification is relevant here ([11.3.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664477%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

Of classes:

> Within an instance constructor or instance function member of a class, `this` is classified as a value. Thus, while this can be used to refer to the instance for which the function member was invoked, it is not possible to assign to `this` in a function member of a class.

Of structs:

> Within an instance constructor of a struct, `this` corresponds to an `out` parameter of the struct type, and within an instance function member of a struct, `this` corresponds to a `ref` parameter of the struct type. In both cases, this is classified as a variable, and it is possible to modify the entire struct for which the function member was invoked by assigning to `this` or by passing `this` as a `ref` or `out` parameter.

Comment: That's for VS .NET 2003. In 2013 it's a little different, but still means the same. And it's *11.3.6* now :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Noted and updated - the up-to-date documentation is actually a much friendlier definition.

Comment: Hmm, seems the link still points to the 2003 documentation and the latest version is only available as a download link - the principle is presumably the same.

Comment: Yes, looks like *11.3.6* has not been changed since then.